# Testing UI router states with $stateChangeStart and $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, testing, angular-ui-router

How does one test with $stateChangeStart or other emitted events?

I have the following code, which in essence checks that the user is logged in, if not, redirect to the `app.login` state

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, AuthenticationService) {

  $rootScope.AuthenticationService = AuthenticationService
  $rootScope.isLoggedIn = AuthenticationService.getIsLoggedIn

  if (!$rootScope.isLoggedIn()) {
    $state.go('app.login')
  }
  // Catch all errors on state change
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    $state.go('app.home')
  })

  // Sets up the role requirements per state
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
    if (AuthenticationService.getIsLoggedIn()) {
    } else {
      if (toState && toState.name !== 'app.login') {
        $state.go('app.login')
      }
    }
  })
})
```

The test I am trying to achieve:

```
'use strict'

describe('Controller', function () {

  var $scope
    , $state
    , $rootScope
    , AuthenticationService
    , $controller

  beforeEach(module('replanApp'))

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    $state = $injector.get('$state')
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope')
    AuthenticationService = $injector.get('AuthenticationService')
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller')
  }))

  describe('Initializers', function () {
    it('should redirect to /login if the user is not logged in', function () {
      $state.go('app.admin.index')
      $rootScope.$apply()
      assert.notOk(AuthenticationService.getIsLoggedIn())
      assert.equal($state.current.name, 'app.login')
    })
  })
})
```

It basically should go to a state, then `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', fn(){})` should have see that the user is not logged in, and transit them to the `app.login` state.

But I am getting `AssertionError: expected 'app.admin.index' to equal 'app.login'`

How would one achieve testing with $stateChangeStart and other events?

Comment: Btw, you have to call `event.preventDefault();` before `$state.go('app.login')`.

Answer (score 2):

I would modify the test to check and see if `$state.go` has been called with `'app.login'` instead of trying to check what the current state is:

```
describe('Initializers', function () {
    beforeEach(function(){
        spyOn($state,'go');
    });
    it('should redirect to /login if the user is not logged in', function () {
      $state.transitionTo('app.admin.index');
      $rootScope.$apply();
      assert.notOk(AuthenticationService.getIsLoggedIn());
      expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('app.login');
    });
  });
```

I can't promise that will fix your test, but it will make it more of a unit test since it won't be relying on `$state.go` to set the current state.

Comment: Doing this I get 'Expected spy to have been called with [ 'app.login' ] but actual calls were [ 'app.admin.index' ]...

Comment: Edited post - use $scope.transitionTo to stop the test failing with the above error. +1 for suggesting to check the $state.go call and not the state change itself, this is the only thing that worked for me from dozens of other suggestions and it makes more sense as a unit test.